# Using comparator for STL set

Tags: c++, stl, comparator

Check the following code:

```
string toLowerCase(const string& str) {
    string res(str);
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < (int) res.size(); i++)
        res[i] = (char) tolower(res[i]);

    return res;
}

class LeagueComparator
{
public:
    bool operator()(const string& s1, const string& s2)
    {
        return toLowerCase(s1) < toLowerCase(s2);
    }
};

int main()
{
    set<string, LeagueComparator> leagues;
    set<string, LeagueComparator>::iterator iter;

    leagues.insert("BLeague");
    leagues.insert("aLeague");    // leagues = {"aLeague", "BLeague"}
    leagues.insert("ALeague");

    for (iter = leagues.begin(); iter != leagues.end(); iter++)
        cout << *iter << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
aLeague
BLeague
```

which is shocking to me. I thought (and expecting) the output would be:

```
aLeague
ALeague
BLeague
```

Before the execution of `leagues.insert("ALeague");`, the `leagues` contains `"aLeague"` and `"BLeague"`. My question is, while executing `leagues.insert("ALeague");` why the machine treats `"ALeague" == "aleague"`? According to my understanding, there is no element `"ALeague"` in `leagues`. So `"ALeague"` should be inserted into `leagues`. The comparator should determine where to put `"ALeague"`.

Thanks in advance.

PS: Please don't hit me for using C style cast. :P I'm too lazy to type `static_cast`.

Comment: The fact that it feels you have to work to perform a C++ style cast is one of the main reason C++ style casts exist -- namely that you should avoid any sort of casting in C++. In this case you should remove the casts completely, and use the correct types instead. I.e. instead of `(int) res.size()`, remove the cast and change `i`'s type to be `unsigned`.

Comment: Also, `i` should be declared in the loop, not outside of the loop. And in C++, toLowerCase should probably just call `std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), std::ptr_fun(tolower))` instead of writing an explicit loop.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: thanks. i need to be used to use `transform()`. that `toLowerCase` was written by me many years ago. i think i didn't know about `transform` at that time. i'll update my codebase.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your comparator, thanks to the `toLowerCase`, says that `"aLeague" == "ALeague"`. Since (according to your comparator) `"aLeague" < "ALeague" == false` and `"ALeague" < "aLeague" == false`, they must be equivalent. And inserting an equivalent element into a set doesn't do anything.

Comment: +1. Note that the comparator is not establishing equality, it is establishing equivalence. There is a difference w.r.t. standard and STL documentation.

Answer (score 4):

When you insert any value to a set, the object checks to see whether it already contains that value. Your `LeagueComparator` object compares `ALeague` with the other two values already in the set. It determines that the existing value `aLeague` is neither greater than nor less than the proposed new entry (`ALeague`), so they must be equal, and so it doesn't proceed with the insert. The set remains with just two elements. That's the whole point of providing a customer comparison object, so you can control how the set determines whether two elements match.

Comment: +1. Note that to be consistent with STL docs, most uses of "equal" here should be replaced with "equivalent". Less-than comparators cannot establish equality.

Answer (score 3):

Given the comparator you provided, "ALeague" is indeed equivalent "aLeague".

Given two values, x and y, and a less-than comparator z:

- If z(x, y) is true, then x is less than y
- If z(y, x) is true, then y is less than x
- If neither is true, then x is equivalent to y
- If both are true, then you have a broken comparator.

Comment: +1, but slight problem with the third bullet w.r.t. STL docs. There is a distinction between equality and equivalence. A less-than comparator cannot establish equality, only equivalence.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: according to STL doc (i don't have it), what are the definitions of `equality` and `equivalence`?

Comment: @Donotalo: Equality is comparison using an equality comparer, or `operator==`. Equivalence is the state where a less than comparer or `operator<` returns false for either ordering of the arguments, as specified here. Conceptually, it's the difference between [equality comparable](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/EqualityComparable.html) and [less than comparable](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/LessThanComparable.html).

Comment: See *Effective STL* Item #19: Understand the difference between equality and equivalence, for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `LeagueComparator` with

```
class LeagueComparator
{
public:
    bool operator()(const string& s1, const string& s2)
    {
        return toLowerCase(s1) < toLowerCase(s2)   ||  
               !(toLowerCase(s2) < toLowerCase(s1))  &&  s1 < s2;
    }
};
```

Comment: That's equivalent to specifying no comparer at all. Your comparator simply returns `s1 < s2` in all cases. (Because `s1 < s2` implies `toLowerCase(s1) < toLowerCase(s2)`) -1

Comment: It's not true. `s1="b"`, `s2="A"`. My comparator returns `false` because of  `false || !true && true = false`. `s1 < s2` returns `true`.